# Excel-VBA: If-Else-Statement on convertion of number to text

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 columns; 1 for month and another 1 is year. Both column having random value. I want to combine both column into 1 single column. As example, in column B "Month" I have this 1-12 number representing month and at Column C "Year" like 8 which is 2008 or 10 for 2010.

My objective is to combine both into 1 column and format it as `mmm YYYY` at Column E such as "Jan 2008".The idea is I want to try Concatenate function as learning the VBA. I have below code to test on converting the month from integer to string, yet it gave me an error

> "Type Mismatch"

and maybe some error on IF-Then-Else statement. I try to improving it but still getting nowhere. Where is my mistake on the IF statement.

```
Sub DateColumn()

'***Defined Variable
  Dim NRows As Integer
  Dim Month() As Integer
  Dim Year() As Integer

'***Read Data
Sheets("Data").Activate
LastRowData = Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row - 1
NRows = LastRowData

'***Redefined Array
  ReDim Month(NRows)
  ReDim Year(NRows)

'***Calculate/Convert
For n = 1 To NRows
'Month= convert integer to string
  If (Month = 1) Then
   Month = "Jan"
  ElseIf (Month = 2) Then
   Month = "Feb"
  ElseIf (Month = 3) Then
   Month = "Mar"
  ElseIf (Month = 4) Then
   Month = "Apr"
  ElseIf (Month = 5) Then
   Month = "May"
  ElseIf (Month = 6) Then
   Month = "June"
  ElseIf (Month = 7) Then
   Month = "July"
  ElseIf (Month = 8) Then
   Month = "Aug"
  ElseIf (Month = 9) Then
   Month = "Sept"
  ElseIf (Month = 10) Then
   Month = "Oct"
  ElseIf (Month = 11) Then
   Month = "Nov"
  ElseIf (Month = 12) Then
   Month = "Dec"
  Else
  End If
Next n

'***Write Output
For n = 1 To NRows
Sheets("Data").Cells(1 + n, 5) = Month()

End Sub
```

I am still new and want "to try and figure" to understand the concept. My code still not properly arranged (sorry) and I want to know how can my code on If-Then-Else be corrected. Thanks Stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi, I think you should check my answer and code below, it's a much shorter and simpler way to get you what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `DateSerial` function, to get a real date out of the values you keep in column B (month) and column C (year), and then just use `NumberFormat = "mmm yyyy"` to get the the format in column A as you want it.

You can shorten your entire code, to something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DateColumn()

'***Defined Variable
Dim NRows As Long, LastRowData As Long, n As Long

With Sheets("Data")
    LastRowData = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row ' last row with data in column B, where you keep your months

    For n = 1 To LastRowData
        .Range("A" & n).Value = DateSerial(2000 + .Range("C" & n).Value, .Range("B" & n).Value, 1)
        .Range("A" & n).NumberFormat = "mmm yyyy"
    Next n
End With

End Sub
```

If you want to get the String (and not the date) use the code below:

```
For n = 1 To LastRowData
    .Range("A" & n).Value2 = Format(DateSerial(2000 + .Range("C" & n).Value, .Range("B" & n).Value, 1), "mmm yyyy")
Next n
```

Comment: Bah of course, `DateSerial()`... You got me there :)

Comment: I am really new, so its new lesson for me thanks. I used this code and worked. although, I am yet not quite sure when to use "option explicit". I learn from book VBA for dummies and maybe not reach that level. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you are attempting to assign a **string** to an **integer**. This is the reason you are receiving the type-mismatch.

```
Dim Month() As Integer
```

but you are trying to use this variable like:

```
Month = "Jan"
```

`"Jan"` is not an Integer, but a string.

---

The next issue is that you are trying to assign different datatypes to the same variable... Again, this would be your month variable (`If Month = 1 Then`)

While you can technically use the type `Variant`, this is not the method you should go with.

Instead, create two variables. If you'd like to use "Month", then maybe something like `Dim intMonth As Integer, strMonth As String`. Assign the column with your Int values to the Integer var, and do the conversion to the String var.

---

I am not entirely sure how many rows you have, but a good rule of thumb is to always declare variables that represent **row numbers** as type `Long` instead of type `Integer`. While you are safe to use Integer on your month & year vars (I'd still use Long anyways), you can run into overflow problems if you have too many rows (integers go up to approx 32.7k, then will overflow afterwards).

---

Next issue, you are using an **array** with `Months()`, but you are referring to `Months` in your If statements as a **non-array**.

```
Sub DateColumn()

      Dim ws As Worksheet
      Dim NRows As Long
      Dim Month As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")        '<-- remove the .Activate
    NRows = ws.Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row - 1

    For n = 1 To NRows
        Select Case ws.Cells(n, "B").Value    '< I think your "Month" col is B?
        Case 1
            Month = "Jan"
        Case 2
            Month = "Feb"
        Case 3
            Month = "Mar"
        Case 4
            Month = "Apr"
        Case 5
            Month = "May"
        Case 6
            Month = "Jun"
        Case 7
            Month = "Jul"
        Case 8
            Month = "Aug"
        Case 9
            Month = "Sep"
        Case 10
            Month = "Oct"
        Case 11
            Month = "Nov"
        Case 12
            Month = "Dec"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Unknown Error in month. Row # [" & n & "], row val = [" & _
                                    ws.Cells(n, "B").Value & "]. Please debug"
        End Select

        ws.Cells(n, "E") = Month & " " & CStr(ws.Cells(n, "C") + 2000)

    Next n


End Sub
```

Comment: I have changed into "String" and still got the same error. Is it because I am using the same words at IF "expression" and Then "statement" that may confused the vba? should I defined more variables?

Comment: You changed into "string" but you are still using `If (Month = 1) Then`, and `1` is still a digit, not a string. Did you see my recommendation on using two different variables? Or using data type `Variant` (NOT recommended)?

Comment: I am sorry. I just see it when the page reload after I comment on my trial. Sorry. Thanks for the code. It worked. Just added disable flickering command and it was working splendidly.

Answer (score 2):

See the attached screenshot...

[image]

The second last column uses the native worksheet function `DATE` (but it requires the cells to be formatted as `MMM YYYY`), the last column uses the custom user function below (gets you to the `2000`, and does not require cell formatting):

```
Function dateConv(month, year) As String
Dim dtOut As Date
 On Error Resume Next
 dtOut = CDate("01" & "-" & month & "-" & year)
 dateConv = Format(dtOut, "MMM YYYY")
End Function
```

The function above uses the `VBA` converter for dates `CDate` and `Format` the result to the format you target.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the new function. I never knew that dateConv I function is exist. I will try it right away.

Comment: Why not just set the format of column to disply only month and year 0 do away with VBA altogether.

Comment: @AJD it all depends on what you want to achieve and how. If you need to create a function that works for a full range rather than one cell,  if you want to just format de cells themselves, etc. The two approaches are good, all depends on your specific scenario(s). However,  you will get more control by using VBA rather than just worksheet functions, and in some cases you will need custom functions to keep things smooth in your formulas.

Comment: @MohamadFaisal: that function, `dateConv` is "home made"; not standard to VBA. The one that is native to VBA and that does the trick there is `CDate`. That is the one that interprets an input _expression_ and tries to figure out which date is that. So, to use it, same approach as yours: copy the code to your module in the workbook and use it in the worksheet formulas. I did not provide a solution for a full `Range` because I think that what you want to achieve is having a function that you can use in a formula (simpler, straight forward to the point). For full _Ranges_ there are other tricks.

Comment: @rellampec: Don't really get more control using VBA. Some work environments lock macros down, and easier to introduce error through poor VBA coding (yes, it happens even in ones as simple as your dateConv function - I have just updated a few). As a simple philosophy, if it can be done in native Excel, do it and leave VBA to to more complex stuff.

Comment: @AJD up to everyone... but yeah, there are things you cannot do with formulas. When you have to treat data constantly, you need to develop tools. Perhaps you cannot share those tools with everyone. However, you did the best you could by the means that were given to you, and that should be good enough. One of my believes is _if it is useful and they cannot do it without it, they should just thank it exists_

Comment: @rellampec: Yes, there are [very few] things that can't be done with formulae, and things that are much easier to do with VBA (hence UDFs). But this particular example is not one of that set. And that is my main point for my comments on this answer. In this instance, it is easier to satisfy the OP's need through a simple Excel in-sheet formula.

Comment: @AJD I get your point, but I did not make the question. And as far as I see, the one that made it, asked for VBA approach, so perhaps they can join the pieces they need to get where they want using not one but multiple answers. As I said, _up to everyone_ ;)

Comment: @AJD thanks for the opinion. As for the date and month, I cannot change the format because it will messed up other linked file. Thus I would like to go for VBA solutions in order to do the conversion.

Comment: @rellampec thanks for the function of `CDate`. It will be useful. I will try it on.  It will better you gave half of it, because the true purpose of my intention is to understand the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Your easiest approach is to use the built-in functionality of Excel.

> My objective is to combine both into 1 column and format it as mmm
>   YYYY at Column E such as "Jan 2008".

Simply place a formula that converts the two cells to a date in Column E, and then format that column to display the date in the format you want. The two pictures below show the formula and the format setting.

[image]
[image]

I have used an arbitrary `day` of `1` in my formula because you are only concerned with the month and year.